# Rails 4 simple_form_for and nested resources undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, simple-form, nested-routes

I'm getting undefined method error:

```
undefined method `challenges_path'
```

I thought I had my form correct, **_form.haml**

```
= simple_form_for [@skit, @challenge], html: { class: "form-horizontal" } do |f|
```

The link to the form above:

```
= link_to 'Submit', new_skit_challenge_path(params[:skit_id]), class: "btn btn-default"
```

This is my routes

```
resources :skits do
  resources :challenges
end
```

This is my **challenge_controller.rb**

```
def new
  @challenge = Challenge.new
end
```

What am I doing wrong? What else information do you need that can help debug this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try doing this:

```
resources :skits, shallow: true do
  resources :challenges
end
```

Answer (score 0):

> undefined method `challenges_path'

The problem is `@skit` is `nil` because you haven't initialized `@skit` in the `new` action.

```
def new
  @challenge = Challenge.new
  @skit = Skit.find(params[:skit_id]) #you need this line
end
```